# QML on Android: MouseArea.onClicked doesn't get called

Tags: android, qt, qml, qt5

I have the following QML file:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import ReaderView 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent

        onClicked: {
            console.log("onClicked!")
        }
    }

    ColumnLayout {
        spacing: 0
        anchors.fill: parent

        CReaderView {
            anchors.fill: parent
        }
    }
}
```

I'm tapping the screen of the Nexus 7 tablet but `onClicked` is never printed in the log. I also tried moving the `MouseArea` inside `CReaderView` to no avail. What's the deal? How can I detect a tap within the window (or, ideally, within the `CReaderView`)?

Comment: What is `CReaderView` and which `QQuickItem`-subclasses does it contain?

Comment: @Mitch: it's a subclass of `QQuickPaintedItem`.

Comment: Does it accept mouse events?

Comment: @Mitch: It has no event filters and no event handlers, so it does whatever the base `QQuickPaintedItem` does.

Comment: Your example works for me if I replace `Item` with `CReaderView`, so it's either a bug that's only affecting you, or it's something in `CReaderView`. By the way, you can't use vertical anchors in a direct child of a `ColumnLayout` (`anchors.fill` uses vertical and horizontal anchors).

Comment: @Mitch: I get no warnings about that. What should I use instead of `anchors.fill`?

Comment: `Layout.fillWidth` + `Layout.fillHeight`.

Comment: @Mitch: doesn't work if I replace `anchors.fill` with `Layout.fillHeight: true` in `CReaderView`.

Comment: *shrugs* That's the correct way to do it. I don't have your full code, so all I can do is speculate.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it's `console.log` that's not working. If I call a `Q_INVOKABLE` method of my C++ class to pass a string and display it with `qDebug()`, I do see the message. So the issue had nothing to do with the `MouseArea`.